# Python - how to distinguish between 2 objects of the same name in a list

Tags: python, object, genetic-algorithm

So i'm making a genetic algorithm in python.  The goal is for the "organism" to get to the top of the screen (x,20).  I have a loop that creates the population which is a list of objects of type "Organism".  Here is the code for the Organism class:

```
class Organism(object):
    def __init__(self, genes,ID):
        self.genes = genes
        self.position = [0,0]
        self.thisTime=str()
        self.geneTranslation = []
        self.ID=ID

    def move(self,d):
        if d == "f" or d == "forward":
            self.position[1] += 1
        elif d == "b" or d == "back":
            self.position[1] -= 1
        elif d == "r" or d == "right":
            self.position[0] += 1
        elif d == "l" or d == "left":
            self.position[0] -= 1

        print(self.position)


    def isInContactWith(self,point):
        point = list(point)
        if self.position == point:
            return True
        else:
            return False


    def run(self):
        for i in range(0,4):
            if i == 0:
                self.geneTranslation.extend(["f"] * self.genes[0])
            elif i == 1:
                self.geneTranslation.extend(["b"] * self.genes[1])
            elif i == 2:
                self.geneTranslation.extend(["r"] * self.genes[2])
            elif i == 3:
                self.geneTranslation.extend(["l"] * self.genes[3])
        r.shuffle(self.geneTranslation)
        for x in range(1,20):
            self.thisTime = r.choice(self.geneTranslation)
            self.move(self.thisTime)
```

As you can see, the genes specify the chance of a particular move.  The problem is in the for loop that creates the population and runs it(ive added prints for debugging):

```
population = []
yValues={}
running = True
BestOrganism=Organism([25,25,25,25],0)
SecondOrganism=Organism([25,25,25,25],1)
for count in range(5):
    for x in range(10):
        a = lambda: r.randint(0, 3)
        c = lambda: r.randint(-1, 1)
        b = BestOrganism.genes
        anOrganism = Organism(b,x)
        anOrganism.genes[a()]+=c()
        population.append(anOrganism)

    for j in range(len(population)):
        print("Organism " + str(population[j].ID) + str(population[j].genes))
        population[j].run()
        yValues[population[j].ID]=population[j].position[1]
        if population[j].position[1]>=20:
            print(population[j].genes)
            running = False
            break

    BestOrganism=max(yValues)

    for k in range(len(population)):
        if population[k].ID==BestOrganism:
            BestOrganism=population[k]
    print(yValues[max(yValues)])
    print(str(population)+"\n"+str(yValues)+"\n"+str(BestOrganism.genes))
    population=[]
    yValues={}
```

No errors pop up but, whenever I try to "mutate" a particular part of the organism's genes with `anOrganism.genes[a()]=c()`, it ends up mutating every organism in the list, even the ones not yet created, so that all of their genes are the exact same at the end (as seen in the final product). Why is python doing this?

Comment: Assignment doesn't create a new list. Your code only creates two `genes` lists, ever.

Comment: anOrganism = Organism(b,popPos)                      anOrganism.genes[a()]=c()                           population.append(anOrganism)

Comment: that creates a new object and adds it to population

Comment: But it doesn't create a new `genes` list.

Comment: In this assignment:  `anOrganism = Organism(b,popPos)`, your new organism is sharing the same `genes` list as `BestOrganism`.  You need to copy the list to avoid that, e.g. `anOrganism = Organism(b[:],popPos)` (or you can copy it in the constructor, depending on how you want to manage it).

Comment: It appends organisms gene list

Comment: why b[:], b is a list.

Comment: That's just an idiom for creating a new copy of an existing list.  It's using list slice notation, with the start and end positions defaulting to the entire list.  It's equivalent to `list(b)`.

Comment: The point is that you are using the same genes list for multiple organisms.  This means that when you modify it in one organism, all of the other organisms that share the same genes list end up with the modification as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of this line: `anOrganism = Organism(b,popPos)`.

So on the first iteration of the loop, you create an `Organism` and set the `self.genes` to `b`. Then you modify the `.genes` of that organism you just created.

When you iterate through the loop again, you are creating a new organism but with the *same exact list*, so it has the changes from the previous one.

Basically, there is only one `b`, and you are setting the `.genes` attribute of *every* organism to point to that *single* list. So any and everytime you change it, it changes for all of the organisms.

What you need to do is be sending in a *copy* of `b` to the constructor of `Organism`.

And then change the line `anOrganism = Organism(b,popPos)` to be

```
anOrganism = Organism(list(b), popPos)
```

Comment: Doesnt the loop reassign b?

Comment: On the surface yes, but it is the same underlying list, it keeps reassigning to the same exact list.

Comment: Why does each object in the list look back at the list b after its genes were already assigned?  if you set a = 2, b = a, a = 3, be still equals 2...

Comment: Integers and lists are _very_ different things. One is an immutable value and the other is mutable.

Comment: Do `a = [1]`, `b = a`, `a.append(2)`, `print b` and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: When you assign a reference to something (e.g., a class, a list, a dict, etc.), Python does not copy those objects.  It merely creates a new reference to the existing object.  If you later modify that object, the change is seen in all references to it.  Try dursk's example and you'll see this.  This is a very basic concept in almost any programming language, and it is something you need to understand if you want to work with object references.

Comment: Then why does python make integers and floats not change when their references do, but makes lists change?  That seems inconsistant.

Comment: An integer is an immutable value. It never changes. `2` is `2`. Wheras a list is mutable, you can add or remove things to it, or even change the elements already in it. You should google around and read up on `mutability` vs `immutability`, as well as `pass by reference` and `pass by value`. It's a much deeper concept than its surfacing in any particular programming language.

Answer (score 0):

The key is these lines:

```
b = BestOrganism.genes
    anOrganism = Organism(b,popPos)
```

The list of genes will be shared by every organism created by that line.  That is, anOrganism.genes is exactly the same object as BestOrganism.genes.  So a change to BestOrganism.genes is seen in anOrganism.genes.

Python has an easy way to make a copy of a list, using "slicing".  Change the line to this:

```
anOrganism = Organism(b[:],popPos)
```

Now anOrganism has its own genes, starting off identical to but still distinct from BestOrganism's genes.

Postscript:

Here is a simplified form, using literal ints instead of the random functions:

```
>>> class Organism(object):
...   def __init__(self, genes, ID):
...     self.genes = genes
...     self.ID = ID
...
>>> zero = Organism([25,25,25,25],0)
>>> one = Organism(zero.genes, 1)
>>> two = Organism(zero.genes[:], 2)
>>> one.genes[2] += 5
>>> two.genes[3] += 7
>>> zero.genes
[25, 25, 30, 25]
>>> one.genes
[25, 25, 30, 25]
>>> two.genes
[25, 25, 25, 32]
>>>
```

Comment: By the time I finished my answer, Dursk had already posted his(/hers).  Genes is just a simple list, so a deep copy is not required.

Comment: No, it didn't work, all of the organism's genes are the same.

Comment: The problem is in anOrganism.genes[a()]+=c()